# Is there a way to print to output console? (twincat3)

Tags: twincat, structured-text

Is there a way to print to output to console like debug.print() in VB.NET using structured text? (twincat3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can send messages through ADS commands from TwinCAT code. The function is called [ADSLOGSTR](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_system/31033611.html?id=9189897725322916238). There also also own functions for DINT and REAL, but the STRING function of course can be used with anything.

The function has three inputs:

- **msgCtrlMask**
- Mask that describes the message type
- Types can be found [here](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_system/31030539.html&id=)
- For example, to show warning message and save it to Windows log: `msgCtrlMask   := ADSLOG_MSGTYPE_WARN OR ADSLOG_MSGTYPE_LOG`
- To show just a Windows MessageBox: `msgCtrlMask := ADSLOG_MSGTYPE_MSGBOX`
- **msgFmtStr**
- The message to be shown as STRING
- A `%s` can be used to add parameter without CONCAT functions. See the last parameter.
- **strArg**
- A STRING that is replaces the `%s` in previous string.

Here is an example the probably is what you need:

```
IF test THEN
    ADSLOGSTR(
        msgCtrlMask := ADSLOG_MSGTYPE_HINT, 
        msgFmtStr   := 'Test message. Parameter is %s', 
        strArg      := 'ABC'
    );      
    test := false;
END_IF
```

When you set the test true, and call the function, you will see this on your Visual Studio error list. Note that it is not written to console.

[image]

I often use error messages (`ADSLOG_MSGTYPE_ERROR`) because I hide notes and warnings quite often and the I wouldn't notice my own entries. Other good way is to add the entry to the Windows log, if you want to log something to be seen later.